# How do you choose which hosting is better for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been planning to host a site built on rails on the web. How can choose the correct hosting site? How do I know they have installed the same version of rails which I worked on? Can I ask the hosting site to install the required rails version and the gems. Or would it be only done to dedicated servers. If you guys wanna suggest any hosting sites, I would also welcome that.

Comment: "u" is not a word. Chat-speak is not allowed here, and indeed it does not reflect well on you *anywhere*. Please take the time to write "you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love so much [heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) because is easy to use and it offer a scalable environment.

But i use dedicated servers with apache+passenger to run my rails application so i can do what i wan't on my system.

Some hosters offers a console to manage your gems so you can run your application in any version of rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you're Linux savvy, you could also go with a VPS solution such as Linode.  A little more work on your end, but you have complete control and will know exactly what versions of what are being used.

Comment: Really you don't even need to be linux savvy beyond general developer ability. Slicehost in particular have very good tutorials which walk through every step of setting up a server. Personally I use linode because they're in the uk and I'm very happy with them.

Answer (score 0):

This website is good to choose Rails hosting http://www.railshosting.org/

Answer (score 0):

i am working for a startup and they are currently hosting at [heroku](http://www.heroku.com). Its built for rails and very good in terms of customer support.

the name "[engineyard](http://www.engineyard.com/)" is being heard these days a lot..you can probably give that a try..

Comment: Is it possible to install any version of rails @ heroku?

Comment: yeah i have been deploying some rails 3.0 apps....they are working fine...